# Does redhat5 servers support md5 encrypted passwords?

Tags: redhat, password

We need to integrate all our systems but we are still running redhat5 based systems.

It is terribly hard to fond documnatation on that on the 'net. The systems which still use rh52 have the man pages removed. It is difficult for us to run tests as these machines are in production.

Normally pam_unix.so has an md5 option (and other encryption options). I know that a long time ago redhat only used crypt. Now I think that introduction of pam also introduced md5, but i am not sure.

If anyone can do a "man pam_unix" on a redhat52 machine and check for the presence of the md5 option that would help us enourmously.

so

Does redhat5 supports md5 encrypted passwords?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command as root

```
system-config-authentication
```

Or you can run

```
setup
```

And it is in the authentication option.

Comment: He's talking about Red Hat Linux 5, not Red Hat **Enterprise** Linux 5.